# how to get the html of a page with php dom?

Tags: php, dom

Is there any way to get the already written html as a variable ? What if the html is already written and someone want to get them on variable?

**Trying to explain more................**

I have  seen many article, tutorials, question, answer about php dom but most of them saying to initialize I must do

```
$html = '<div><h1>Sample Title</h1></div>';
$dom = new domDocument;
// load the html into the object
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

That means I have to assign dom element to a variable.

but do not want to create the variable $html, I just want to get all html of that php file where the code situated and modify them before deliver to client like browser.Such as:

```
<html>
<body><div><h1>Sample Title</h1></div></body>
</html>
$dom = new domDocument;    
$dom->loadHTML(the above html);
```

Is there any way? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are you asking out to get the output of the current PHP program before it has finished running?

Comment: file_get_contents if you want the content, or if you want it included in the page, use include.

Comment: May be yes I want to get the html before going to browser and want to make change of it.I do not know is it possible or not. @ Quentin

Comment: file_get_contents is used to get another file but I want content of the same file @ Hammerstein

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Paste a chunk of HTML into your script and then use DOMDocument to create a dom model with it?

Comment: yes @ i alarmed alien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the output that would normally be sent to the browser as HTML, use output buffering:

```
ob_start();

// Generate your HTML

$output = ob_get_contents();
```

Now you can operate on the value of $output before sending it to the browser. To stop buffering without sending output, use:

```
ob_end_clean();
```

To send the output in its current form, use:

```
ob_end_flush();
```

To make changes to the output before sending it, you can use 'ob_end_clean()' to stop buffering without sending the contents of the buffer, then make your changes, then echo or otherwise output the modified HTML.

```
ob_end_clean();
$modifiedHTML = // Do something with $output
echo $modifiedHTML;
```

Comment: can you wrote me what is the problem in the question? How can I improve it?